# Sapply Returning Same Value for New Var in Every Row

Tags: r

`Var` is a metric in a Data Frame with 105 rows: (zero NaNs) all unique values.

I am trying to use `sapply` to create a new variable by running `df$var` through the below function:

```
df$newVar<- sapply(df$var.g, function(x) .01**(.95**(x/max(x)*100)))
```

`df$newVar` is generated and added to `df`, but rather than showing a different number in each row (every value of `df$var` is unique), it's returning the same number in each row.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried applying on the vector directly ? 
R is vectorized and works really great this way

```r
custom_func <- function(x) {
  0.01^(0.95^(x/max(x)*100))
}
var <- 1:10
custom_func(var)
#>  [1] 0.06346381 0.19187931 0.37215381 0.55331913 0.70163307 0.80883587
#>  [7] 0.88070937 0.92676420 0.95548367 0.97310329
```

Try on `df$var.g` directly

```r
df$newVar <- 0.01^(0.95^(df$var.g/max(df$var.g)*100))
```

or using a custom function

```r
custom_func <- function(x) {
  0.01^(0.95^(x/max(x)*100))
}
df$newVar <- custom_func(df$var.g)
```

Comment: the custom function worked, thank you!!!! if you don't mind, can you provide some detail on why sapply doesn't work here?

Comment: With sapply here, you iterate over the values inside the vector, one by one. so `max(x) == x` as `x` is of length 1. So `x/max(x) = 1` and you get the result of `custom_func(1)` (0.97)
R works well vectorized and most functions can apply on a vector. There is even a `Vectorise` function to help vectorize a function that is not.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful/educational!